# Dealing with Django translation inside AngularJS partials (ng-view)

Tags: angularjs, django, translation, multilingual

I'm having problems with the translation service provided by Django inside AngularJS partials. It seems Django is translating the content inside a partial only the first time my website is loaded. As of now I'm providing `index.html` with Django and then loading each view with ng-view directive. I got django and angular routing working nicely. 
Inside my Django templates folder I have
[this structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpWQA.png). Each of these files is just a regular html template with some content being translated by Django.

My django `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^$', views.homepage, name='index'),
    url(r'^views/page-home.html/$', views.homeView),
    url(r'^views/(?P<page>[-\w]+.html)/$', views.angularViews),
    url(r'^(?P<path>.*)/$', views.angularRedirector),
)
```

And inside my angular `app.js`:

```
$routeProvider
    // Load home by default
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/page-home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
    })

    // home page
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'views/page-home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
    })

    // contact page
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'views/page-contact.html',
        controller: 'contactController'
    })

    // otherwise
    .otherwise({ 
        redirectTo: '/' 
    });
```

My `index.html` structure looks like this:

```
<!-- index.html -->
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Head stuff [...] -->
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
    <!-- some content -->
    <h1>{% trans "Hello world" %}</h1>

    <!-- Views are injected here -->
    <div class="page {$ pageClass $}" ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And one of the templates, for example `page-home.html` looks like this:

```
<!-- page-home.html -->
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
<!-- more content -->
<h2>{% trans "Goodbye World" %}</h2>
```

I'm currently working with 3 languages (English, Spanish and Deutsche). If I load `localhost:8000`, Django will automatically redirect to `localhost:8000/es/#/`, since Spanish is my default browser language. All content will render nicely, so DOM looks like this:

```
<!-- [...] -->
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
    <!-- some content -->
    <h1>Hola mundo</h1>
    <!-- Views are injected here -->
    <div class="page page-home" ng-view>
        <!-- more content -->
        <h2>Adiós mundo</h2>
    </div>
</body>
<!-- [...] -->
```

Here is where things get tricky. If i go to `localhost:8000/de/#/` or `localhost:8000/en/#/`, just the content directly inside `index.html` will be translated to the current language, while the content inside ng-view will remain the same. So if I change to Deutsche my DOM will render like this:

```
<!-- [...] -->
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
    <!-- some content -->
    <h1>Hallo welt</h1>
    <!-- Views are injected here -->
    <div class="page page-home" ng-view>
        <!-- more content -->
        <h2>Adiós mundo</h2>
    </div>
</body>
<!-- [...] -->
```

Guess what, if I change the browser language to Deutsche, then all the content will render to Deutsche but if I visit `localhost:8000/en/#/` or `localhost:8000/es/#/`, only the content outside ng-view will change. I don't understand what is happening here. How do I get the language to change inside the ng-view according to the url language, not the browser language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it working. It turns out Angular will set the Accept-Language header only once, so the content inside ng-view would only translate once considering the browser's language.
So in my app.js configuration I had to store the language from the url and set the Accept-Language header on every request:

```
app.config(["$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {
    var language = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept-Language"] = language;
}]);
```

That solved my problem.